# How to make EF.net filter all the data on SQL Server and not on C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I was doing some tests using Entity Framework .Net core. I turned on the SQL server profile and I started to compare my query and what EF executes on SQL Server.

Here is my modal class:

```
public class Offer : BaseModel
    {
        public DateTime HostStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime HostEndDate { get; set; }
        public int Guests { get; set; }
        public decimal AmountOffer { get; set; }
        public OfferStatus Status { get; set; }
        public PaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }

        public long CityId { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsVisible => HostStartDate.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date;



        public void SetSoftDelete()
        {
            IsDeleted = true;
            Bids.ToList().ForEach(n => n.SetSoftDelete());
        }
    }

 public class Bid : BaseModel , IStateAware
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public override long Id { get; set; }

        public long OfferId { get; set; }
        public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }

        public long PropertyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Property Property { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Accepted { get; set; }
        public bool Read { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ModelState State { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsPayed => Accepted.HasValue;

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsAccepted => Accepted.IsNotNull();

        public void SetSoftDelete()
        {
            IsDeleted = true;
            State = ModelState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

I have a generic class to do my Find, like this:

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> FindBy(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> includeProperty = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter.IsNotNull())
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (includeProperty.IsNotNull()) 
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy.IsNotNull())
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        return query.AsNoTracking();
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
var finalEnd = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, end.Day, 23, 59, 59);
var data = await _bidRepo.FindBy(n => !n.OfferId.Equals(offerId)
                                            && n.PropertyId.Equals(propertyId)
                                            && !n.IsDeleted
                                            && !n.IsAccepted
                                            && !n.IsPayed
                                            && !n.IsInvalidate
                                            && ((n.Offer.HostStartDate.Date >= start.Date && n.Offer.HostStartDate.Date <= end.Date) ||
                                            (n.Offer.HostEndDate > finalEnd && n.Offer.HostEndDate.Date <= end.Date))
                                            ).ToListAsync();
```

My query returns 4 items, and it is fine. But, on SQL server Profile my query are not take care of any thing different of the dates.

This is the profile:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [n].[OfferId], [n].[PropertyId], [n].[Accepted], [n].[CreatedBy], [n].[CreatedDate], [n].[IsDeleted], [n].[IsInvalidate], [n].[ModifiedBy], [n].[ModifiedDate], [n].[Read]
FROM [Bids] AS [n]
INNER JOIN [Offers] AS [n.Offer] ON [n].[OfferId] = [n.Offer].[Id]
WHERE ((CONVERT(date, [n.Offer].[HostStartDate]) >= @__start_Date_2) AND (CONVERT(date, [n.Offer].[HostStartDate]) <= @__end_Date_3)) OR (([n.Offer].[HostEndDate] > @__finalEnd_4) AND (CONVERT(date, [n.Offer].[HostEndDate]) <= @__end_Date_3))',N'@__start_Date_2 datetime2(7),@__end_Date_3 datetime2(7),@__finalEnd_4 datetime2(7)',@__start_Date_2='2020-02-23 00:00:00',@__end_Date_3='2020-02-25 00:00:00',@__finalEnd_4='2020-02-25 23:59:59'
```

On this SQL server statement, I can't see any of boolean filters or Ids.

How can I make sure all clauses are executed on SQL server and not bringing part of the date to C# and later removing it?

Comment: Use a stored procedure.https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: That's strange and normally should not happen. Could you provide the `Bid` and `Offer` classes + their fluent configuration (if any). Also the EF Core version.

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev, I just updated the information with my classes.

Comment: A stored procedure is not necessarily required.  You can use a [Raw SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), or [partial raw queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq).

Comment: Good point @RobertHarvey, but why I will use it? Using LINQ will be easier to track changes on a modal for example. I think my scenario happens only on EF. core.

Comment: As with everything else in programming, you have to weigh the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some EF Core implementation quirks here, but the main issue is that you are using not mapped / get only properties which cannot be translated to SQL. EF Core 3.0+ will simply throw runtime exception, but EF Core 1.x / 2.x will evaluate such conditions in memory after retrieving the data from the database.

Why they cannot be translated? Because EF Core is not a compiler and all it sees is something like

```
public bool IsPayed { get; }
```

In order to be translatable, EF Core must "see" the implementation inside the query expression tree. Which means that basically you can't use such properties (and also custom methods like your `IsNotNull`) in LINQ to Entities query and should code them directly eg. instead of

```
&& !n.IsPayed
```

you should use

```
&& !n.Accepted.HasValue
```

Similar for `&& !n.IsAccepted` (and most likely `!n.IsInvalidate`).

Of course this is code duplication and less readable, but this is a general problem with `IQueryable` expression trees which has no compiler or BCL solution. There are some 3rd party libraries which try to address it. For instance, [Lambda Injection](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/#lambda-injection) from [NeinLinq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#neinlinqentityframeworkcore). If you insist using OOP in your data model / queries, consider using some of these 3rd party libraries because you won't get it form C# / BCL / EF Core.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivan, How about the IDs (!n.OfferId.Equals(offerId) && n.PropertyId.Equals(propertyId)) EF are not able to translate it? Must I change Equals to == ?

Comment: @AFetter They seem to not cause issues. So although in general using `==` and `!=` is preferable, it's not mandatory in this case. The weird thing is that EF Core removes (some) translatable expressions along with non translatable. So when you have issue, comment out all criteria parts and start adding them one by one, run, look at the generated query to see which one is causing it.

Comment: You are right Ivan Stoev. Soon I remove the !n.IsPlayed and used the proper property all other filters appeared on my query.